# NuGet error "External packages cannot depend on packages that target projects" when installing SNAP 1.4

Tags: nuget

I get the following error when trying to install SNAP 1.4 into a fresh VS2010-project using Nuget 1.3: 
"External packages cannot depend on packages that target projects"

Is this a problem with the SNAP Nuget package, or am I doing anything wrong?

> PM> Install-Package SNAP 
>   'Castle.Core (≥ 2.5.2)' not installed. Attempting to retrieve dependency from source...
>   Done. 
>   Install-Package : External packages cannot depend on packages that target projects. 
>   At line:1 char:16 
>   + Install-Package <<<<  SNAP 
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException 
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId :  
> NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: Report the issue to the package author. People need to test their packages :).

Comment: Wow :( I assumed that if someone had uploaded a package, they would've at least installed it to test it. It might have been tricky to do locally (due to the dependency issue fixed recently), but when it's live there's no excuse! :(

Comment: The error happens with Knockout.Mapping 1.0 as well.

Answer (score 3):

Reading this issue here:

http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/595

It sounds like it happens if a project that doesn't have any Content relies on one that does. Not sure whether this always fails, or just when there isn't a "current project". I do remember seeing a "Default Project" dropdown in the Package Manager Console, so not really sure why this wouldn't work.

Can you try installing it through the UI? (right-click the references folder of the project, then do Add Library Package (or similar)). Also check you have a project selected in the Solution Explorer and/or the Default Package in the console window.

Comment: So how do you nuget the SNAP pack (no pun intended)? Don't tell me I have to download it manually and bring that Lib folder back to life.

Answer (score 0):

That's no longer the case. SNAP package can be successfully installed into a project. My environment is VS 2012 + NuGet 2.7.